# Ubuntu stuck in tablet mode

Tags: 22.04, lts

I recently switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04 and usually use sleep to close my laptop. But today when I got back, my laptop started in tablet mode and now isnt going back to laptop mode. I cant even access the home screen, all i can access is the lock screen where if i type my password and then press enter (using the on-screen keyboard, physical one is not being detected) it isnt logging me in. Even backspace on the digital keyboard isnt being registered. Please anyone help me, im a student and have many important things on my laptop. Please tell me in comments what should I do to provide more details regarding the error. Mouse and touchpad are working.

Edit: Here is the footage of my laptop turning on: https://www.mediafire.com/file/n9c380xelg9xaoy/20230810_200436.mp4/file
I usually get those errors everytime I startup.

Pls ignore the noise in background, thats my online class going on, I thought it would waste a lot of time to remove the background noise so just left it, my tablet sound doesnt mute (in which im listening the class).

Edit 2: I did something that seem to have worked. I disabled everything from the accessibility menu expect the on-screen keyboard. Then the key board worked as normal and it let me login. The I pressed super+L to go back to the lock screen and it is back to the laptop UI. Can anyone explain me what have I done exactly and how did it fix the issue? I think the sticky keys option was not allowing me to press enter on the on-screen keyboard. (Or wasn't it tablet mode this whole time?)